# what is _origin in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

in odoo sale order line there is an onchange method `_onchange_product_uom_qty()` where they used a condition `self.product_uom_qty < self._origin.product_uom_qty`
Now my question is what does self._orgin is used for what does it return?

Note: 1. you can also find the origin in hr_appraisal module inside the onchange_colleagues method and somewhere in purchase 
2. I does not  mean this origin- "source document"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an onchange context it is the old value/record which was used before the change.