# Odoo Discard Change When an Exception Occurred

Tags: python, odoo

I need to discard the change user made when an exception occurred, to go back to the value when input is valid.

For example I have 2 field `check_in` & `check_out` as `Date` type. I need to check the `check_in` must be smaller than `check_out`. When the `check_in` is bigger than `check_out`, an exception dialog shows. When the user closes the exception dialog, I need to discard the change for `check_in`.

```
@api.onchange('check_in', 'check_out')
def validate_check_in(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.check_in > rec.check_out:
            raise ValidationError("Not valid check in and check out")
```

Comment: Which Odoo version is this question for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the method of discarding the changes. However, I do have a workaround in case you haven't got one.

By using [_origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165008/what-is-origin-in-odoo), you can get the original values before the `onchange` is triggered. So, when the exception is going to occur, you can just set the value(s) back to its original state, which is almost similar to discard.

The code should be something like this.

```
@api.onchange('check_in', 'check_out')
def validate_check_in(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.check_in > rec.check_out:
            rec.check_in = rec._origin.check_in # Added for the workaround
            raise ValidationError("Not valid check in and check out")
```

If you don't like this solution, please wait a bit longer in case there's someone who knows how to discard because I also want to know that.

Comment: It still not working. When I log the value of rec._origin.check_in, it give me a `False` value

Comment: @NMNaufaldo Maybe it is False because the field was empty(False) before onchange?